How to capture request body in Jenkins
I am hitting Jenkins pipeline remotely via a REST call where the request contains parameters to process the pipeline. The URL params are retrieved using params.urlparam in the pipeline syntax. I have a long string which cannot be sent as a URL param and instead I am planning to send it via the request body. But is there any provision in jenkins to retrieve the incoming request body?
Tried sending the request value as a param in url but as it contains few special characters, it is not possible. Hence, looking at the option of sending it in request body.

Yes, Jenkins takes parameter from both the query string and the request body. You can even mix them.
curl -X POST -u user:token "https://JOB_URL/buildWithParameters?FOO=1" --data "BAR=3"

See more information here.
The length of the string is technically limited, but the limit is high enough that in reality you are very unlikely to hit it. To work around the special characters you would need to url-encode them. Most languages have libraries that would do it for you, like requests in Python.

Thanks for the reply @Iterokun. But I am using a Ht tp client to invoke jenkins where I pass url parameters. If I pass the request body in a JSON format, jenkins is unable to retrieve the same via parameters. How should Jenkins be configured to read the body of the request?

It's a fair assumption to make that a REST API would accept JSON formatted data, but Jenkins doesn't. It accepts application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I'm afraid you cannot configure it to accept anything else, but you can change your request format.
